# Asp.Net MVC 4 Model binding AND knockout binding to select element

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, select, knockout.js

I have a page where it currently is using a model property for the "list" of items to select from, as well as a property "selectedItems" for the ones that are already selected. (This is a multi-select element).

My problem is, when using the select element like this:

```
<select name="SelectedItems" id="SelectedItems" multiple class="form-control chosen-select" data-placeholder="Select Your Items" style="width: 100%">
    @foreach (var item in Model.AvailableItems)
    {
        var itemSelected = Model.SelectedItems.Contains(item) ? " selected " : "";
        <option value="@item.ToString()" @itemSelected>@item.Humanize()</option>
    }
</select>
```

It pre-selects the appropriate items, and the list of items available is perfect. But when I go to save/post, it doesn't recognize any changes since that element wasn't included in the knockout binding.

So, when I include it with the knockout binding, like this:

```
<select name="SelectedItems" id="SelectedItems" multiple class="form-control chosen-select" data-bind="selectedOptions: selectedItems" data-placeholder="Select Your Items" style="width: 100%">
    @foreach (var item in Model.AvailableItems)
    {
        var itemSelected = Model.SelectedItems.Contains(item) ? " selected " : "";
        <option value="@item.ToString()" @itemSelected>@item.Humanize()</option>
    }
</select>
```

It will NOT load the already selected items, but it DOES see the changes that are made when trying to save/post.

It's worth noting, that when I put a breakpoint in the knockout code (see below) where it renders the view model, right BEFORE it does the ko.applyBindings(), you can see in the browser that it DOES have the selected items correctly pre-selected. Then, once the ko.applyBindings() executes, those pre-selected items go away.

Here's the knockout stuff that is in a script section/tag in my cshtml file:

```
var viewModelJson = '@Html.Json(Model)';
var viewModelJs = {};
var viewModel = {};
viewModelJs = JSON.parse(viewModelJson);
initializeViewModelJs(viewModelJs);
viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(viewModelJs);
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

How do I get this to work for both: 1) loading currently selected items, and 2) seeing the changes made to the selected items?

Answer (score 1):

When the page loads and renders initially, because you have the options marked as selected, they render as selected. Once the binding to the viewmodel takes place, I suspect the `selectedItems` array is empty so the items are no longer selected and they are cleared.

My solution would be to do everything in the viewmodel. Have the list of options, use the `options` binding as well as the `selectedOptions` binding. Because you are mixing server and client side code, this is causing this behavior.

Keep in mind that the DOM is being controlled by the viewmodel. It reflects the state of the viewmodel properties via the `data-bind:` bindings.

Perhaps you can setup the state of the `Model` object that you are converting into JSON and then into a viewmodel to match the state of the DOM you want or write a JavaScript viewmodel.